# Numbering my equations

Tags: equations, amsmath

how can I add numbering to this equation and make it more elegent??

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
[0] & [m] \\ 
[m] & [c]  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
\vec{\ddot x}  \\ 
\vec{\dot x}  
\end{Bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
-[m] & [0] \\ 
[0] & [k]  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
\vec{\dot x}  \\ 
\vec{x}  
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{Bmatrix} 
\vec{F}\\
0
\end{Bmatrix}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{equation} ... your matrices ... \end{equation}`? It is strange mixing square brackets with curly braces ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
[0] & [m] \\ 
[m] & [c] 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
\vec{\ddot x}  \\ 
\vec{\dot x}  
\end{Bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
-[m] & [0] \\ 
[0] & [k]  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
\vec{\dot x}  \\ 
\vec{x}  
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{Bmatrix} 
\vec{F}\\
0
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]